# Set Global Variable from WebOS Service Request Result

Tags: javascript, webos

I'm trying to get LG Smart TV WebOS Device Unique ID. I have to use LG WebOS' API to do that, which I did. But the problem is, I cannot get the API call result and set it as global variable. I want to use the variable globally, not only onSuccess function(inResponse). Can anyone teach me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

```
    function getUDID() {

        webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.sm", {
            method: "deviceid/getIDs",
            parameters: { 
                "idType": ["LGUDID"]        
            },
            onSuccess: function (inResponse) {
               var serial = inResponse.idList[0].idValue
                var udid = serial;
                // console.log(udid);

            },                

        });

    }
    getUDID();
```

I expect the output would be a variable that I could use globally across any other functions.

var udid = 'xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx';

Answer (score 0):

Set it to window:

var window.TVUDID = getUDID();

and then access through window

console.log('TV UDID: ' + window. TVUDID);